# mod_filter: Why does a SUBSTITUTE not work for certain URLs?

Tags: apache, mod-filter

I'm using *mod-proxy* in combination with *mod-filter* to make an internal server (nginx) accessible from outside of the network. My filter configuration is:

```
SetEnv filter-errordocs # necessary to process requests which don't have HTTP 200 OK
FilterDeclare ghe
FilterProvider gzinflate INFLATE resp=Content-Encoding $gzip
FilterProvider ghe SUBSTITUTE resp=Content-Type $text/
FilterProvider gzdeflate DEFLATE Content-Type $text/
FilterChain +gzinflate +ghe +gzdeflate
FilterTrace ghe 1
```

This works fine for HTML pages, for which `curl -I http://internal/url` gives something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: server.com
Date: Sat, 10 Aug 2013 14:55:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
X-Frame-Options: deny
Set-Cookie: logged_in=no; domain=.192.168.120.128; path=/; expires=Wed, 10-Aug-2033 14:55:25 GMT; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: _fi_sess=xyz HttpOnly
X-Runtime: 19
ETag: "zyx"
Content-Length: 5928
```

However, it does not work when accessing e.g. *css* files for which `curl -I http://internal/url.css` gives something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: server.com
Date: Sat, 10 Aug 2013 14:55:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 269455
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 14:23:05 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

The problem is somehow visible in Apache's error log (with debug LogLevel). For URLs to which the filter is applied, I see something like this (not sure if the `EOS`-part is the same request, though):

```
[Sat Aug 10 16:44:27 2013] [debug] mod_headers.c(756): headers: ap_headers_output_filter()
[Sat Aug 10 16:44:27 2013] [debug] mod_filter.c(117): [client 192.168.93.201] ghe
[Sat Aug 10 16:44:27 2013] [debug] mod_filter.c(122): [client 192.168.93.201] ghe: type: HEAP, length: 8096
[Sat Aug 10 16:44:27 2013] [debug] mod_filter.c(117): [client 192.168.93.201] ghe
[Sat Aug 10 16:44:27 2013] [debug] mod_filter.c(122): [client 192.168.93.201] ghe: type: HEAP, length: 8096
[Sat Aug 10 16:44:27 2013] [debug] mod_filter.c(117): [client 192.168.93.201] ghe
[Sat Aug 10 16:44:27 2013] [debug] mod_filter.c(122): [client 192.168.93.201] ghe: type: HEAP, length: 1097
[Sat Aug 10 16:44:27 2013] [debug] mod_filter.c(122): [client 192.168.93.201] ghe: type: EOS, length: 0
[Sat Aug 10 16:44:27 2013] [debug] mod_filter.c(117): [client 192.168.93.201] ghe
[Sat Aug 10 16:44:27 2013] [debug] mod_filter.c(122): [client 192.168.93.201] ghe: type: EOS, length: 0
```

For URLs for which the filter is not applied, I just see something like this:

```
[Sat Aug 10 16:44:27 2013] [debug] mod_headers.c(756): headers: ap_headers_output_filter()
[Sat Aug 10 16:44:27 2013] [debug] mod_filter.c(117): [client 192.168.93.201] ghe
[Sat Aug 10 16:44:27 2013] [debug] mod_filter.c(122): [client 192.168.93.201] ghe: type: EOS, length: 0
```

So, just `EOS`, but no `HEAP`, if that does mean anything.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUBSTITUTE` filter may not work with `Accept-Ranges: bytes`. Using *mod-header* and adding following line to the Apache configuration file:

```
Header set Accept-Ranges "none"
```

will make the filter work.